# Laravel custom validation error while using after_or_equal more than one for same attribute

Tags: php, laravel, date, validation, laravel-8

if i need do this validation

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    'start_date' => [
        'after_or_equal:today',
        'after_or_equal:'.$event->start_date.'',
        'before_or_equal:'.$event->end_date,
        'required',
    ],
    'end_date' => 'required|before_or_equal:'.$event->end_date,
]
```

and need to return custom messages for each `after_or_equal:today` and                     `'after_or_equal:'.$event->start_date.''`, how can do this in laravel 8?

Comment: Looks like you have a scenario that requires a custom rule. Try `php artisan make:rule CustomRule`

Comment: Please search by "Simple Custom Validation Rules Example" and check custom validation rules example.

Comment: @Rager 
can give me sample example related to my situation

Comment: @AhmedOthman I'd have to spend time playing around with it, I've never written a custom rule before.

Comment: After 'end_date' => 'required|before_or_equal:'.$event->end_date, add blank array [ ]
Inside this array give your message like below`
`[
   'start_date' => [
        'start_date.after_or_equal' => 'Add your message what you want to show'
    ]`